# How can I display pdf file from local public/uploads folder in laravel into html <iframe>

Tags: html, iframe

> code below:

```
 <iframe id="ifrm" src="/public/uploads/sample.pdf" />
```

> iframe prompt 404|Not Found, does path/src is wrong path?

Comment: Try to use ./uploads/sample.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrong `PATH` use this:

```
 ./uploads/sample.pdf
```